# Should you mention runtime permission in Manifest?

Tags: android, permissions

I'm using `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` runtime permission. However, the app seems to be working fine even when I didn't mention `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in my manifest file.

**Question:** What are the implications of adding / not adding runtime permissions in manifest and the common best practices around permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably experiencing is that the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is all but deprecated starting with Android 10. This is part of Google's Scoped Storage enforcement:

https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage

You're supposed to declare runtime permissions in AndroidManifest. Try the same thing with another dangerous permission and see if it acts the same way.

Comment: I think that makes sense, let me try that out!

Answer (score -1):

Beginning with Android 4.4 (API 19), there is no need to request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission when your app wants to write its own application-specific directories on external storage(provided by getExternalFilesDir() method). However, to make your app compatible with levels <= 18, you will need the uses-permission tag.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />`

Comment: I'm accessing non-application directories as well, so this is not applicable for my use case.